# Can someone help me understand this Stack overflow error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am not the best coder so if you could explain to me why and what I should do to solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

When I run the program I am able to input everything but at the end it highlights the first scanner line with the java.lang.stackoverflowError.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;
public class Login
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void createAccount(){
        System.out.print("Create a 6 digit account number: ");
        int createNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Create a 4 digit PIN: ");
        int createPin = input2.nextInt();
        Login acc = new Login();
        acc.loginScreen(createNumber, createPin);

    }
    public void loginScreen(int createNumber, int createPin){
        System.out.println("Enter your acocunt number: ");
        int accEntryNumber = input.nextInt();
        int lengthNum = String.valueOf(accEntryNumber).length();

        System.out.println("Enter your pin: ");
        int accEntryPin = input2.nextInt();
        int lengthPin = String.valueOf(accEntryPin).length();
        if(accEntryPin == createPin && accEntryNumber == createNumber){
            Main access = new Main();
            access.mainMenu();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Access denied");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: when i run the program i am able to input everything but at the end it highlights the first scanner line with the java.lang.stackoverflowError

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: post the full stack trace please

Answer (score -1):

You can use one single scanner for your whole program. Like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Object;
public class Login
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void createAccount(){
        System.out.print("Create a 6 digit account number: ");
        int createNumber = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Create a 4 digit PIN: ");
        int createPin = input.nextInt();
        Login acc = new Login();
        acc.loginScreen(createNumber, createPin);

    }
    public void loginScreen(int createNumber, int createPin){
        System.out.println("Enter your acocunt number: ");
        int accEntryNumber = input.nextInt();
        int lengthNum = String.valueOf(accEntryNumber).length();

        System.out.println("Enter your pin: ");
        int accEntryPin = input.nextInt();
        int lengthPin = String.valueOf(accEntryPin).length();
        if(accEntryPin == createPin && accEntryNumber == createNumber){
            Main access = new Main();
            access.mainMenu();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Access denied");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same exact error, is it possible the error is in a different class? it shows the error being the scanner in this login class

Comment: It might be in a different class. I'm not getting the error when I run this code.

Comment: I use "Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);" in most other classes, could that be a problem?

Comment: still the same issue